How to make my tables better?

This is the result of my tables at the moment but i feel that even though it displays satisfactory ish, its not written the optimal way. I am using the array package.
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[calc]{datetime2}
\usepackage[margin=1in, includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Font encoding
\usepackage{graphicx} % For including images
\usepackage{amsmath} % Enhanced math support
\usepackage{amsfonts} % Additional math fonts
\usepackage{amssymb} % Additional math symbols
\usepackage{hyperref} % Hyperlinks
\usepackage{natbib} % Bibliography management
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{array}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, arrows.meta, calc, quotes}
\usepackage{tocloft} % For customizing ToC
\usepackage{cancel}
% Custom units
\DeclareSIUnit{\kgf}{kgf}


\begin{document}

\section{Dados Registados na Fase 1}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1em}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\vspace{5em}
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|M{5.5cm}|M{1cm}|M{1cm}|M{1cm}|M{1cm}|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{\large{\textbf{Carga de Torção}} \hfill \normalsize b = \SI{180}{\milli\meter}} \\
    \hline
    $P$ [\si{\newton}] & 5 & 10 & 15 & 20 \\
    \hline
    Extensão de Torção 1 [\si{\micro\varepsilon}] & 25 & 51.9 & 77.8 & 104.1 \\
    \hline
    Extensão de Tração 1 [\si{\micro\varepsilon}] & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.8 & 4.7 \\
    \hline
    Extensão de Torção 2 [\si{\micro\varepsilon}] & 26.5 & 53.7 & 80.9 & 108.5 \\
    \hline
    Extensão de Tração 2 [\si{\micro\varepsilon}] & 0.1 & 0.2 & 1.2 & 0.2 \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Valores obtidos experimentalmente para a Torção}
\end{table}
\vspace{2em}
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|M{5.5cm}|M{1cm}|M{1cm}|M{1cm}|M{1cm}|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{\large{\textbf{Carga de Tração}}} \\
    \hline
    $Q$ [\si{\kgf}] & 11 & 13 & 15 & 17 \\
    \hline
    Extensão de Torção 1 [\si{\micro\varepsilon}] & 2.2 & 2.5 & 2.0 & 3.0 \\
    \hline
    Extensão de Tração 1 [\si{\micro\varepsilon}] & 35.8 & 42.4 & 49.3 & 56.6 \\
    \hline
    Extensão de Torção 2 [\si{\micro\varepsilon}] & 1.1 & 1.4 & 1.6 & 1.8\\
    \hline
    Extensão de Tração 2 [\si{\micro\varepsilon}] & 39.8 & 46.3 & 53.6 & 60.4 \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Valores obtidos experimentalmente para a Tração}
\end{table}
\vspace{2em}
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|M{6cm}|M{6cm}|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\large{\textbf{Carga Combinada}} \hfill \normalsize $b = \SI{180}{\milli\meter}$} \\
    \hline
    & Q = \SI{17}{\kgf} e P = \SI{20}{\newton} \\
    \hline
    Extensão de Torção 1 [\si{\micro\varepsilon}] & 107\\
    \hline
    Extensão de Tração 1 [\si{\micro\varepsilon}] &  52.3 \\
    \hline
    Extensão de Torção 2 [\si{\micro\varepsilon}] &  109.7 \\
    \hline
    Extensão de Tração 2 [\si{\micro\varepsilon}] &  61.8 \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Valores obtidos experimentalmente para Torção e Tração}
\end{table}

\end{document}

It would be great to have an explanation on how to understand LaTeX tables better. I need the tables to be centered and in each cell be centered as well (vertically and horizontally).
Thank you so much in advance.

Have a look at https://texdoc.org/serve/booktabs.pdf/0 It has a lot of information, how to create professional looking tables

... and as you are anyway loading the siunitx package, you could use it to properly align your numbers.
